# from development to production - uploading a webpage

Tags: reactjs, web, localhost, production-environment

First of all, I will excuse myself for possibly making vague questions.

I am a newby freelancer webdeveloper, and I recently created a webapplication which works fine on my own computer, running it on localhost.

More recently, using A2Hosting, i bought a domain and some server space, and my objective is to upload my application in order to make it online for anyone.

However, right now, I am having a few problems.
Specifically, I do not know how to upload my web application.
Basically, what I did was upload all the folders and files I had on my local machine into the server, and I was hoping that would work.

Unfortunatly, the server continues to display the "initial" site I uploaded. a simple, static, htlm file saying hello world. This file is the index.html that is inside the "www" folder.

The directory of the server is presented in the following figure.
[image]

My question is how do I make the server display the content of react/redux page, instead of the simple static html initialy uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with react however with Angular you would have to run through the same process on the server as you would to run the app locally but with the server variables in place of the local variables.

For example on angular I have to compile and run my front/back ends and ensure my database is also live for it to run at all otherwise nothing would work on the server .

Check what configs need changing to process the change from local to dev

Hopefully that is at least a little bit helpful, the below article should be useful to you.

https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-deployment-5a717d4378fd

Comment: i appreciate your answer and will look into it!